# Getting "Syscall param execve(argv) points to unaddressable byte(s)" in valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

Running the following C program with `valgrind --leak-check=yes` results in valgrind giving an output indicating that

```
Syscall param execve(argv) points to unaddressable byte(s)
```

The program is as follows:

```
int main() {
  const int NUM_ARGS = 3;
  char** run_arguments = malloc(sizeof(char*)*NUM_ARGS);
  run_arguments[0] = "ls";
  run_arguments[1] = "-l";
  run_arguments[2] = "--color";
  char* full_path = "/bin/ls";
  int pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
    execv(full_path,run_arguments);
  else {
    int status;
    waitpid(pid,&status,WUNTRACED);
    free(run_arguments);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

According to valgrind, the problem occurs on the line `execv(full_path,run_arguments);`, and the problem originates from the `malloc` done on the line `char** run_arguments = malloc(sizeof(char*)*NUM_ARGS);`.

What mistake have I made that causes valgrind to give this output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument list must be terminated by a `NULL` pointer. Add one element to the `run_arguments` array, and have it be a `NULL` pointer.

Without the null pointer argument, the `exec` functions will go out of bounds in their search for the terminator, and will treat every non-null element as an argument that should be passed to the program. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

This is clearly noted in [the `exec` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html).